# Capturing onbeforeunload when page is contained in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've set up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kteq5xw/) to try to verify if the beforeunload event is triggered when the page is used in an iframe.

Since the fiddle show its result in an iframe, I figured it could be easy to verify by just closing the page. I've set up a request bin at pipedream just to see if any requests gets sent, but it doesn't seem to trigger in Chrome.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    fetch('https://eoaczcjrpegb7wv.m.pipedream.net')
}
```

Is is possible to use this event from an iframe or do I need to look in to a different approach?

After a closer look it seem to capture *some* of the requests. Is this prone to race conditions? If so, are there any more robust alternatives?

Comment: This theoretically should be possible, according to this answer. I think in general your approach should work if not blocked by any `sandbox` parameters of iframe. Now, jsfiddle has the following `sandbox` parameters `allow-modals allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-downloads`. You can see that `allow-modals` is there so theoretically this should be possible. However, I tested it with a server of mine and it didn't work. Also even the default popup didn't appear which appears when you return a string from `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: @JAAAY Yeah, as I mentioned in the question I got some flaky results, so feels like a matter of if you're lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition.  Since your event handler does nothing to stop the page unload in any way (it does not even trigger a confirmation prompt to delay it), immediately after your event handler is processed, the browser will proceed to unload the page.  This aborts most pending requests; if a request did not manage to be submitted at that point, it will not be sent to the server at all.

Sending a request from a `beforeunload` event handler is a poor idea anyway.  For starters, you are not even guaranteed that the event will fire at all; the browser may be unable or unwilling to trigger the event.  MDN warns that it will only fire after the user had interacted with the page and it may fail when the session is terminated out of browser’s control.  [The only legitimate purpose of `beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes) is to check whether the page contains any unsaved state that the user may lose, and to trigger a confirmation prompt; even that should be understood to work on a best-effort basis.  Anything else is prone to abuse and suspect; I would not be surprised if a future browser plug-in or vendor ‘intervention’ were to block all web requests when a page is about to unload.

However, if you insist, there are ways to make the request survive unload.  You can use [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    navigator.sendBeacon('https://example.net', '');
};
```

or the `keepalive` fetching option:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    fetch('https://example.net', { keepalive: true });
};
```

Chrome provides both, but Firefox, as of version 106, only implements the former.  Using those APIs comes with some restrictions: at any given moment, the total amount of data sent by active keep-alive requests must fit within 64 KiB, as per [the Fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-or-cache-fetch).

You may notice [using those APIs in a `beforeunload` handler is still not recommended usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon#avoid_unload_and_beforeunload), as it worsens performance of navigating back to the page with the back button.  MDN suggests listening for the `visibilitychange` event, but that is of course not the same thing.

Last but not least, nothing stops the user from having the browser lie to you that the request has been sent, like with this uBlock filter:

```text
##+js(no-fetch-if, keepalive:true)
##+js(set, navigator.sendBeacon, trueFunc)
```

So try not to be too obnoxious with your <del>spyware</del> ‘analytics’.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. To elaborate, what I do is send a tracking event / data layer push to GTM to track how many % of the video on that page that the person has watched. I wouldn't really know that they're finished until they actually leave the page - and I don't want to continuously send "watched x %" to GTM with some fixed interval. Maybe there's an alternative approach and I'm barking up the wrong tree here

Comment: For my use case, there seems to be support for utilizing the sendBeacon api with a flag, I think that's my best bet.